# Asset path in scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and in a `.scss` file I want to use a image as background.
Now i'm using `asset_path` to get the real name of the image in production

```
    background:url(asset_path('fundoteste.jpg'))
```

But, when go to production, the background doesn't work and the code shows up like this:

```
background:url("/assets/fundoteste-99a689875895552ae788148d716b8c4722af6218c82bc265e77e12834eb40eaf.jpg")
```

But this image is the same folder thata scss that call it (assets) and this way it is calling `assets/assets/`

How can I remove the `/assets` before the image and still using `asset_path` to get the production name of the image?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following `background:url(image-url("filename.jpg"))`